# Narrowing TypeScript indexed type via generics

Tags: typescript

Consider below type:

```js
type RequestSpecification = {
  type: "get" | "post";
  parameters: { [key: string]: ParameterSpecification }
};

type ParameterSpecification = {
    required: boolean;
    // ...
}
```

Now it to create the variable like this:

```js
const requestSpecification: RequestSpecification = {
    type: "get",
    parameters: {
        id: {
            required: true
        },
        nickname: {
            required: false
        }
    }
}
```

we can call not existing properties of `requestSpecification.parameters`:

```
// no error!!!
console.log(requestSpecification.parameters.asdf);
```

I want TypeScript will know that only `id` and `nickname` available among `parameters`.
How can I solve it via generics?

Comment: Do you have the `strict` flag on in your tsconfig.json?

Comment: @Evert, yes, I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string index type that you are using tells TypeScript that `parameters` can have any property that is a string. In other words, `'asdf'` (and any other strings) are allowed to be properties. What are not allowed are numbers as properties. Since that is the type you declare, TypeScript is behaving as expected, because it is allowing `'asdf'` as a property on `parameters`.

This is a common confusion about string index types, and it will likely cause you surprise over and over again in your TypeScript career.

One way that you can narrow the type is [to use a generic like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=51#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYBlSBjAlgMxywENgcB7AOwB4AFKCAD2AgoBMUo0AnHCgcwB8UALxQA3gCgoUUJABcUAER8IwRVAA%20SsGTSKA3FKhgiXIgFtVELigVioAbQDSUXlBoBdBTVMWrXTAhcAmJSSigAXwkIwwlZaB8zS2YA7HxCEnIKEXEjLgREHHzWBQAjMjIAGwgiCkMoiSxKNCh8pFQMNJDMygU4drRA4Iyw6gByHFYxzSgxikIAawo-MaFRSWlpeIVlVUUAGiNpEyT-W1zNy9cSi6u7tsLihWAuZCOriMO76XmsJb87O9vq0CkUIDc8ERKigIEDNlFLlEGk0KCgqhAAHSVMh8AAUDw6Q3SoSyGJOfhSKAxRBQrDwAEp9EA). In the following example, we are saying that `P` extends string. As a result, `parameters` remains constrained to string properties. When we instantiate the type, we are passing in a string union of `'id' | 'nickname'`. That tells the compiler exactly which two strings are allowed.

```
type RequestSpecification<P extends string> = {
  type: "get" | "post";
  parameters: { [K in P]: ParameterSpecification }
};

type ParameterSpecification = {
  required: boolean;
}

const requestSpecification: RequestSpecification<'id' | 'nickname'> = {
    type: "get",
    parameters: {
        id: {
            required: true
        },
        nickname: {
            required: false
        }
    }
}

// This will now be a compiler error. Hooray! 
console.log(requestSpecification.parameters.asdf);
```